# Using MongoDB-Spark connector (> 10.x) how do I read a Map type successfully from the database (now returns as a Struct)

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am updating some of my company's code to move from an older version of spark to something more modern (Spark 3.3.1).  As part of this, I also am upgrading our spark-mongodb connector code (Moving from mongo-spark-connector 2.4.2 to 10.1.1) but I am running into a weird issue.  If create a spark DataSet that is based on a simple case class that contains a scala Map[String, Long] as one of its fields it gets read back from the database as an odd struct type and I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is or how to get the new Spark-mongo connector to read it back as a typed object.

In the previous version of the code, I could simply use the MongoSpark companion object's `load[T]` method with the T being the case class description of the object I wanted back and it "just worked".  However, in the newest version of the API, the MongoSpark companion object seems to be gone (at least I cannot find it XD).

Below is a complete minimal example showing this off, and I would love a hand figuring out what I am missing in this upgrade

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset}
import com.mongodb.spark._

case class SimpleOutput(_id: String, name: String, mapInfo: Map[String, Long])


import spark.implicits._
val data1 = SimpleOutput("d1", "Test Data 1", Map("starfleet" -> 10, "serenity" -> 13))
val data2 = SimpleOutput("d2", "Test Data 2", Map("NAMCO" -> 1981, "Nintendo" -> 1985))
val data3 = SimpleOutput("d3", "Test Data 3", Map("Sonic" -> 3, "Tails" -> 2, "Knuckles" -> 5))
val inputData = Seq(data1, data2, data3)
val inputDS = spark.createDataset[SimpleOutput](inputData)
inputDS.printSchema()
inputDS.write.format("mongodb")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .options(Map("connection.uri" -> "MyConnectionURI",
               "database" -> "MyDatabaseName",
               "collection" -> "MyCollectionName",
               "replaceDocument" -> "false"))
  .save()
val readConfigOptions = Map("connection.uri" -> "MyConnectionURI",
                            "database" -> "MyDatabaseName",
                            "collection" -> "MyCollectionName",
                            "sql.inferSchema.mapTypes.enabled" -> "true")

val outputDF = spark.read.format("mongodb").options(readConfigOptions).load()
outputDF.printSchema()
outputDF.count() shouldBe 3
outputDF.as[SimpleOutput].collect() should contain theSameElementsAs inputData
```

This will fail with the following error:
"The deserializer is not supported: need a(n) "MAP" field but got "STRUCT<Knuckles: BIGINT, NAMCO: BIGINT, Nintendo: BIGINT, Sonic: BIGINT, Tails: BIGINT, serenity: BIGINT, starfleet: BIGINT>"."

The calls to print the schema's illustrate the problem
inputDS' schema:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mapInfo: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = false)
```

Which is exactly as I would expect, however outputDF's schema is NOT

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mapInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Knuckles: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- NAMCO: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Nintendo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Sonic: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Tails: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- serenity: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- starfleet: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Now, I am passing the option (which according to Mongo defaults to true anyway) `sql.inferSchema.mapTypes.enabled` as set to true, so I am confused as to why I am seeing this behavior.  In the past (mongo-spark connector 2.4.2) I had done the following to read my data back from Mongo and it worked:

```
val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "MyConnectionURI", "database" -> "MyDatabaseName", "collection" -> "MyCollectionName"), None)
MongoSpark.load[SimpleOutput](spark, readConfig)
```

I am not sure where to go from here, the [Mongo docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/read-from-mongodb/) are (IMO) lacking and simply imply this will "just work". I cannot find anything about this elsewhere.  Thanks for any help people can provide, I am thoroughly lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in order for the mongo-spark connector to correctly interpret the schema, I needed to use Scala's reflection to generate a schema for the T type in the code.  This seems a serious short coming in the new driver, but it is simply one of many I have found and have had to work around.  But, the following code works for any case class I have attempted so far, no matter how complex:

```
def readAs[T <: Product : TypeTag](databaseName: String, collectionName: String,
                                     partitionerConfig: Option[MongoPartitionerConfig] = None): Dataset[T] = {
  import spark.implicits._
  val props = mongoProps(databaseName, collectionName, partitionerConfig)
  val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[T].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

  spark.read.format("mongodb")
       .options(props)
       .schema(schema)
       .load()
       .as[T]
}
```