# Why is Mongo Spark Connector v10.1 Giving Terrible Performance compared to v2.4?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am hoping someone has an idea or has seen similar issues, but I am in the process of upgrading a code base at work to use the newer Mongo spark connector and am finding TERRIBLE performance under the new connector--with everything else the same.

Previous code (entirely a Scala project) was developed using the Mongo-spark connector v2.4 and we could query a Mongo DB collection that contained a few hundred million documents into a Dataset[T] in ~30 minutes (not great, but we lived with it).  Upgrading our code to use the Mongo Spark Connector v10.1 and changing the code in the most minimal way has resulted in the EXACT same query taking just shy of 4 HOURS.  This is querying against the EXACT same Mongo database, we have made no changes what so ever to it, only the code.  Here is the code that we are using:
The code under mongo spark connector v2.4:

```
def readAs[T <: Product : TypeTag](databaseName: String, collectionName: String,
                                     partitionerConfig: Option[MongoPartitionerConfig] = None): Dataset[T] = {
  import spark.implicits._
  val props = mongoProps(databaseName, collectionName, partitionerConfig)
  MongoSpark.load[T](spark, mongoReadConfig(props)).as[T]
}
```

Since Mongo (despite what their [documentation says](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/v10.1/read-from-mongodb/)) completely got rid of the MongoSpark companion object and re-wrote the code in Java, I changed the code under mongo spark connector v10.1 to:

```
def readAs[T <: Product : TypeTag](databaseName: String, collectionName: String,
                                     partitionerConfig: Option[MongoPartitionerConfig] = None): Dataset[T] = {
  import spark.implicits._
  val props = mongoProps(databaseName, collectionName, partitionerConfig)
  val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[T].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

  spark.read.format("mongodb")
       .options(props)
       .schema(schema)
       .load()
       .as[T]
}
```

The reflection to build the Schema is needed because the new mongo-spark connector cannot correctly infer the schema (despite what the documentation says--not the only place it is flat out wrong >:( ) and actually solves my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76150733/using-mongodb-spark-connector-10-x-how-do-i-read-a-map-type-successfully-fro).  In both cases we are not using any custom partitioner.

On smaller sized database, I have not seen such a performance hit, there is a slight one, but nothing unmanageable (or even really measurable in many cases). I cannot believe that this is an acceptable loss of performance to anyone, but I also cannot find any thing else really discussing this and am hoping someone might have a suggestion as to a way forward.

Comment: How do you measure this duration? Did you had a look to execution plan? Is it strictly loading from Mongo that takes this long?

Comment: Also, did you try a more progressive upgrade using intermediate versions to identify which version brings the issue? Maybe it has changelog with more details.

Comment: Last thing: could it be that other dependencies must be upgraded as well for consistency?

Comment: Duration is measured via Datadog, looking at the time the query begins and monitoring how long the Mongo instance's CPU is being used.

As to a more progressive upgrade, Mongo-spark connector went from v2.4 to v10.0 so I _could_ go back to v10.0 (we are on v10.1), but I don't think that is going to do too much.

And yes, we added checkpoints to ensure that this code was isolated and not an execution plan gone on too long.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to determine what had happened here.

It turns out that this was due to the new version of the mongo-spark connector trying to be helpful.  While not in our read code (which was posted above), a short while later we took the resultant dataset that was returned and did a `.withColumn("newColumnName", explode("fieldInsideDataframe"))`.

In the old mongo-spark connector, the generated mongo query was simply an aggregation pipeline that requested EVERYTHING in the collection (which is what we wanted, and needed).  The new mongo-spark connector (v10+) attempted to be clever, took this explode (that we wanted spark to do) and tried to create a mongo aggregation pipeline query that did it.  Needless to say, the mongo query it crafted was abysmal, and utterly killed our performance.

I/we were able to resolve this by simply adding a call to checkpoint the Dataset immediately after the read statement to keep the mongo-spark connector from trying to be clever and harming us in the process.  So if you are using the v10+ of the connector, be VERY wary of what queries it attempts to produce because they may be extremely suboptimal.